# SetState() called in constructor

Tags: checkbox, flutter, setstate, statefulwidget

I've build a Custemized List. Now I include a Checkbox and if I would checked or unchecked , the following error was thrown: 'setState() called in constructor'

```
class Lists extends StatefulWidget{  
     @override
    _List createState() => _List();
}

class _List extends State<Lists> {  
  bool checkedvalue = true;
  @override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {

 return futureBuilder();
}

Widget futureBuilder(){  
  var futureBuilder = new FutureBuilder(
      future: rest.fetchPost(),
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
        switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
          case ConnectionState.none:
          case ConnectionState.waiting:
            return new Text('loading...');
          default:
            if (snapshot.hasError)
              return new Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}');
            else                    
                return listBuilder(context, snapshot);            
        }
      }
 );

 return new Scaffold(         
      body: futureBuilder,
    );
}

Widget listBuilder(BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {  
  List<rest.Status> values = snapshot.data;

  if (values == null || values.length == 0){
    return null;
  }


  int items = values.length;

  return ListView.builder(   
  itemCount: items,
  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
    String statusText;
    Image image ;
    Uint8List bytes;

    if(statusList.globalStatus != null){
      for(int i=0;i< statusList.globalStatus.length; i++){
        if(values[index].statusID == statusList.globalStatus[i].id){

            if(statusList.globalStatus[i].kurzform != null){
              statusText = statusList.globalStatus[i].kurzform;
            }else{
              statusText = statusList.globalStatus[i].kurzform;
            }

            if (statusList.globalStatus[i].icon != null){
              bytes = base64Decode(statusList.globalStatus[i].icon);
              image = new Image.memory(bytes) ;
            } 
        }

        if(image== null || statusText == null){            
          statusText= 'Kein Status';
          image=  new Image.asset('assets/null.png');
        }              
      }
    }   
    return new Container( 
      decoration: new BoxDecoration(
          border: Border(top: BorderSide(
          color: Colors.black26,
          width: 1
          )
        )
      ), 


      child:Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          CustomListItemTwo( 
            statusText: statusText,                               
            status:image,
            materialNR: values[index].uArtText,          
            material: values[index].untersuchungsMaterialName,
            probenArt:  values[index].probenart,
            eingansdatum: values[index].eingangsdatumText,
            patient: values[index].vorname + ' ' + values[index].nachname ,
            geburtsdatum: values[index].geburtstagText ,

          ),
          Checkbox(            
              value: checkedvalue ,           
              onChanged: (bool newValue) =>                
                setState(() {
                  checkedvalue = newValue; 
                })              
            ),
        ] 
      ),
    );
  }       
  );
}

}
```

I/flutter ( 5067): ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY GESTURE ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
I/flutter ( 5067): The following assertion was thrown while handling a gesture:
I/flutter ( 5067): setState() called in constructor: _List#9044e(lifecycle state: created, no widget, not mounted)
I/flutter ( 5067): This happens when you call setState() on a State object for a widget that hasn't been inserted into
I/flutter ( 5067): the widget tree yet. It is not necessary to call setState() in the constructor, since the state is
I/flutter ( 5067): already assumed to be dirty when it is initially created.

Comment: please accept the answer if it solved your problem, so the question will not remain as unanswered :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My code below is not testet.

There is somewhat a concept error in your code. You should **NOT** fetch anything inside your build method!

If you put a print e.g. "building..." in your build-method (as I did below) you will see why. The build method is called more than you might think. So you are calling a WebService or whatever more then once, the response will come more then once. Actually the `setState()` method will trigger a build.

If you want to pull something at the beginning use the `initState()` method. This method will be called once when the state was created. Use Variables for the state of the call and react to it in the build Method (as said before `setState()` will trigger a rebuild).

I refactored your code a bit, having this concept in mind, your switch/checkbox problem probably will be gone.

Also please take a look how to use Futures https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-async/Future-class.html

```
class Lists extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _List createState() => _List();
}

class _List extends State<Lists> {
  bool checkedvalue = true;
  bool loading = true;
  AsyncSnapshot asyncSnapshot = null;

  @override
  void initState() {
    futureBuilder();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print("building...");
    if(asyncSnapshot != null && asyncSnapshot.hasError){
      return Text("Error : ${asyncSnapshot.error}");
    }
    return (loading) ? Text("LOADING") : listBuilder(context, asyncSnapshot);
  }

  void futureBuilder() async {
    rest.fetchPost().then((snapshot) {
      switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
        case ConnectionState.none:
        case ConnectionState.waiting:
          setState(() {
            loading = true;
          });
          break;
        default:
          if (snapshot.hasError) {
            setState(() {
              loading = false;
            });
          } else {
            setState(() {
              loading = false;
              asyncSnapshot = snapshot;
            });
          }
      }
    });
  }
  .....
```